# Wants to hide content from the background of navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, customization

[image]

As shown in the above picture, the text is showing behind the navbar. It would be great if you please guide me on how I would hide this text from my navbar when I scroll up my content. Should I make a custom class of CSS properties? or if there any built in bootstrap 4 class?

Answer (score 0):

Add a z-index value for your content and navbar. navbar's z-index value must be larger.
The example below will help you understand how it works.

[CSS z-index property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

example:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.first-div {
  background: red;
  
  /* change this z-index value */
  z-index: 2;
}

.other-div {
  position: absolute;
  background: lime;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  
  /* change this z-index value */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <span>first div</span>
</div>

<div class="other-div">
  <span>other div</span>
</div>
```